# foreach() every 4 change output

Tags: php, foreach

I have an issue where I don't know for a foreach() loop to change the output on every(x) amount of results.

Here is my foreach() code:

```
$dir_handle = 'assets/icons/';
    foreach(array_diff(scandir($dir_handle), array('.', '..')) as $file) {
        $cut = substr($file, -4);
        echo '<a href="action.php?do=changeicon&set=' . $cut . '"><img id="preload_header" src="assets/icons/' . $file . '" /></a><br />';
}
```

How would I get it for that 1-4 have the same result, but then 5-8 have a different result, and then back to 1-4?

Comment: What you are looking for is the [modulus operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php). Take a look at this [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936242/php-how-do-you-determine-every-nth-iteration-of-a-loop)

Comment: Use incrementor, when it reaches a number that can be divided to 4, do something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do a count in your foreach loop

```
$count = 1;
foreach(array_diff(scandir($dir_handle), array('.', '..')) as $file) {
    //Check if count is between 1 and 4
    if($count >= 1 && $count <= 4) {

        //Do something

    } else { //Otherwise it must be between 5 and 8

        //Do something else

        //If we are at 8 go back to one otherwise just increase the count by 1
        if($count == 8) {
            $count = 1;
        } else {
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you sir, are smart! Good Job

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `%` operator, combined with a division by `4`:

```
foreach ($a as $key => $val) {
    $phase = $key / 4 % 2;
    if ($phase === 0) {
        echo 'here';
    }
    elseif ($phase === 1) {
        echo 'there';
    }
}
```

This switches between the two branches every 4 iterations of your loop.

As pointed out in the comments, the above method assumes that the keys of your array are in order. If not, you can add a counter variable in the loop, like:

```
$c = 0;
foreach ($a as $val) {
    $phase = $c++ / 4 % 2;
    if ($phase === 0) {
        echo 'here';
    }
    elseif ($phase === 1) {
        echo 'there';
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes all the keys are in sequence