# Arrange divs on new row every third time

Tags: php

I have this most annoying problem; I'm trying to arrange three divs on a row, and then new row, and another three divs and so on, like this:

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-1">1</div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">2</div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-1">4</div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">5</div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">6</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

As for this accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936272/4892914),

> There is one catch: 0 % 3 is equal to 0. This could result in
>   unexpected results if your counter starts at 0.

So how would i implement this into this code:

```
 <div class="col-md-8">
            <?php
            foreach($this->movies->movie_data as $key => $movie){
                $string = file_get_contents("http://example.com/?t=" . urlencode($movie->movie_titel). "&y=&plot=short&r=json");
                $result = json_decode($string);

        if($result->Response == 'True'){ 
            ?>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <?php if($result->Poster == 'N/A') : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo Config::get('URL')?>ladybug/day/<?php echo $this->city ?>/<?php echo $movie->movie_id ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo Config::get('URL')?>/images/na.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
                <?php else: ?>
                <a href="<?php echo Config::get('URL')?>ladybug/day/<?php echo $this->city ?>/<?php echo $movie->movie_id ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $result->Poster; ?>" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div><b><?php echo $result->Title; ?></b></div>
                <div><i><?php // echo $result->Plot; ?></i></div>
            </div>

    <?php }else{ ?>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="<?php echo Config::get('URL')?>ladybug/day/<?php echo $this->city ?>/<?php echo $movie->movie_id ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo Config::get('URL')?>/images/na.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
                <div><b><?php echo $movie->movie_titel ?></b></div>
                <div class="plot"><i><?php //echo 'N/A' ?></i></div>
            </div>       

            <?php }}} ?
            </div>
```

For some reason, divs is arranged like this:
[image]

**My question:** How do I arrange thumbnails on a new row, every third time?

Answer (score 0):

[Found the answer in the other Q](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18773759/4892914)... Didn't read, sorry about that.

```
            <?php }
            if (($key + 1) % 3 == 0) { ?>
                </div>
            <?php   }
            }} ?>
```