# Limit number of foreach is iterating to display a message before continuing

Tags: symfony, loops, foreach, swiftmailer

I'd like to interrupt my foreach loop after e.g. 50 loops, to then display a message saying "50 out of xxx emails sent out" and then continue the foreach for the next 50, show a message again, continue and so on..

Is there a way to do this?

My loop:

```
          $i = 0;
          foreach ($users as $user) {

          if(!in_array($user->getEmail(), $receivers)){
          $recipient = $user->getEmail();
          $this->get('MailerHelper')->sendMessage('..,$recipient,..');
          }

           $i++;
           if($i % 50 == 0){
            printf('50 Emails sent.');
           }
          }
```

Comment: Please fix your indention. It will make your question more readable.

Comment: sorry, you're right

Comment: Just create a variable outside the loop to count the iterations, like `$i`, and do `$i++` in the loop. Then in the loop, you can have an if statement for `$i % 50 == 0` (i.e, $i is divisible by 50) where you can print the line. No need to break out of the loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How do you determine every Nth iteration of a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936242/php-how-do-you-determine-every-nth-iteration-of-a-loop)

Comment: Hm, I tried the iterator, but I still end up in a timeout.. I added my counter, so that you can see what I did. 
I thought by interrupting the forloop I can avoid a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly - you are almost there:

1. You don't need an explicit increment variable - foreach has that key already available.
2. You likely want to skip the initial modulus TRUE (first iteration) otherwise you display having sent X emails when you haven't even started.

> ```
> $users = ['Jim', 'Bob', 'Fred', 'Shane', 'Chris', 'Larry', 'John'];
>
> $batchTotal = 3;
>
> foreach ($users as $index => $user) {
>     if (!in_array($user->getEmail(), $receivers)) {
>         $recipient = $user->getEmail();
>         $this->get('MailerHelper')->sendMessage('..,$recipient,..');
>     }
>
>     // NOTE: $index > 0 skips first modulus test when $index == 0
>     if ($index > 0 && ($index % $batchTotal == 0)) {
>         printf("$batchTotal Emails sent.\n");
>     }
> }
> ```

I had to dump the code example into a blockquote and code block - wouldn't properly highlight code otherwise.

Alex