# Add 3 <td> inside every <tr> loop

Tags: php

I am retrieving data from the DB and want to fill a table with 3 `<td></td>` per `<tr></tr>` Here's what I have:

```
foreach($extras AS $key => $extra){
                                if($key % 3 == 0){
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                }
                                echo "<td>
                                    <input type='checkbox' data-price='$extra->precio' value='$extra->id' name='extras[]' id='extra-$extra->id' />". $key . " 
                                        <label for='extra-$extra->id'>
                                            <img class='mx-auto d-block' src='" . $this->config->item('base_url') . "assets/" . $extra->extra_uri . "' alt='$extra->nombre' />
                                            <p class='kit text-center'>$extra->nombre</p>
                                        </label></td>
                                ";
                                if($key % 3 != 0){
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                }
                            }
```

It gives me a weird table, however if I do it with `$key % 2` then it gives me a good table with 2 td's inside, for whatever reason, I just can't make it work with 3.

I looked at: [PHP: How do you determine every Nth iteration of a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936242/php-how-do-you-determine-every-nth-iteration-of-a-loop) but that's pretty much what I've done to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$_eol = 0;
foreach($extras AS $key => $extra){
if($key % 3 == 0 || $key == 0){
    $_eol++;
    echo "<tr>";
}
echo "<td>
    <input type='checkbox' data-price='$extra->precio' value='$extra->id' name='extras[]' id='extra-$extra->id' />". $key . " 
        <label for='extra-$extra->id'>
            <img class='mx-auto d-block' src='" . $this->config->item('base_url') . "assets/" . $extra->extra_uri . "' alt='$extra->nombre' />
            <p class='kit text-center'>$extra->nombre</p>
        </label></td>
";
if($_eol == 3 ){
    echo "</tr>";
    $_eol = 0;
}
}
```

I think there will be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

try with given code

```php
echo "<tr>";
foreach($extras AS $key => $extra){
echo "<td> <input type='checkbox' data-price='$extra->precio' value='$extra->id' name='extras[]' id='extra-$extra->id' />". $key . " <label for='extra-$extra->id'> <img class='mx-auto d-block' src='" . $this->config->item('base_url') . "assets/" . $extra->extra_uri . "' alt='$extra->nombre' /> <p class='kit text-center'>$extra->nombre</p> </label></td> "; 
if($key % 3 == 0){ 
  echo "</tr><tr>"; 
} 
}
```