# PHP foreach and modulus operator multiple iterations

Tags: php, foreach, modulo

I am trying to recreate this structure by using a php foreach and modulus. I am trying to save hundreds of lines of code with this. The structure i am trying to replicate is this:

```
<div class="item-holder">
    <div class="item"><?=$giant_conch->Tooltip();?><?=$giant_conch->TooltipEth();?><?=$giant_conch->randomTooltip();?><div class="item-name"><?=$giant_conch->name;?></div></div>
    <div class="item-description hidden-on-mobile"><?=$giant_conch->createDescr();?></div>
    <div class="item"><?=$basinet->Tooltip();?><?=$basinet->TooltipEth();?><?=$basinet->randomTooltip();?><div class="item-name"><?=$basinet->name;?></div></div>
    <div class="item-description hidden-on-mobile"><?=$basinet->createDescr();?></div>
    <div class="item"><?=$full_helm->Tooltip();?><?=$full_helm->TooltipEth();?><?=$full_helm->randomTooltip();?><div class="item-name"><?=$full_helm->name;?></div></div>
    <div class="item-description hidden-on-mobile"><?=$full_helm->createDescr();?></div>
</div>
<div class="uniques-rowside"></div>
```

This is what i have so far thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936242/php-how-do-you-determine-every-nth-iteration-of-a-loop) post

```
<?php
$counter = 0;

foreach ($all_helms_assoc_array as $name=>$item) {

    $counter++;
    if (($counter - 1) % 3 == 0) {
        echo "<div class='item-holder'>";
        
    }

    echo "<div class='item'>" . $item->Tooltip() . $item->TooltipEth() . $item->randomTooltip() . "<div class='item-name'>" . $item->name . "</div></div><div class='item-description hidden-on-mobile'>" . $item->createDescr() . "</div>";
    
    
    if (($counter - 1) % 3 == 0) {
        echo "</div>";
        
    }
    if ($counter % 3 == 0) {
        echo '<div class="uniques-rowside"></div>';
    }
}
?>
```

I am very close. The only problem i have is that the closing `</div>` of the flex holder `<div class="item-holder">` needs to happen at 3, 6, 9, 12 etc iteration. Basically this part

```
if (($counter - 1) % 3 == 0) {
    echo "</div>";
    
}
```

Comment: instead of `($counter - 1) % 3 == 0` use `$counter % 3` then whenever counter has a value of a multiple of 3 it will result in a remainder of 0, i.e. 0, 3, 6, 9, ..., 3n. Might only have to add a test for counter not being 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$counter = 0;

foreach ($all_helms_assoc_array as $name=>$item) {

    if ($counter === 3){
        echo "</div>";
        $counter =0;
    }

    $counter++;
    if (($counter - 1) % 3 == 0) {
        echo "<div class='item-holder'>";
        
    }

    echo "<div class='item'>" . $item->Tooltip() . $item->TooltipEth() . $item->randomTooltip() . "<div class='item-name'>" . $item->name . "</div></div><div class='item-description hidden-on-mobile'>" . $item->createDescr() . "</div>";
    
    
    if (($counter - 1) % 3 == 0) {
        echo "</div>";
        
    }
    if ($counter % 3 == 0) {
        echo '<div class="uniques-rowside"></div>';
    }
}
if ($counter != 0)
{
    echo "</div>";
}
```

It seems that all 3 iterations need to be "DIV" closed.

Therefore, whenever the counter reaches 3 I close you div, and initialize it (a modulo can also be performed).

The reason if a new if was inserted is to avoid printing  the first time you enter the first iteration.

Comment: How about some description and an explanation of what was changed and why.

Comment: the <div class="item-holder> needs to close with </div> on 3, 6, 9, 12 etc iteration. everything else seems in order but it currently it doesn't do that. The item-holder div encompases all the other class=item or class=item-name divs.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a lot of trial and error to acomplish this task and it's almost impossible for someone else to do it. So what i did to solve this was use `echo "Now we are at iteration: " . $counter;` on all foreach stops and made changes accordingly. The final resulst is this:

```
<?php
// This is a complex foreach that will be displaying the entire items page in

// start the counter
$counter = 0;

// Loop through the assoc array of the item type held in the object file
foreach ($all_helms_assoc_array as $name=>$item) {
// increment the counter on each iteration
$counter++;
    // Every 1,4,7,10,13,16 etc iteration
    if (($counter - 1) % 3 == 0) {
        echo "<div class='item-holder'>";
    }
    // Every iteration
    echo "<div class='sox" . $item->max_sockets . "'>";
    echo "<div class='item'>" . $item->Tooltip() . $item->TooltipEth() . $item->randomTooltip() . "<div class='item-name'>" . $item->name . "</div></div>";
    // Close the item and sox div classes on 1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11,13,14 etc iteration
    if ($counter % 1 == 0) {
    echo "<div class='item-description hidden-on-mobile'>" . $item->createDescr() . "</div></div>";
    }
    // Close the item-holder div on 3,6,9,12,15 etc iteration
    if (($counter + 3) % 3 == 0) {
        echo "</div>";        
    }
    // Display the rowside div on 3,6,9,12,15 etc iteration after the item-holder div has been closed
    if ($counter % 3 == 0) {
        echo '<div class="uniques-rowside"></div>';
    }
}
```